# Wordpress add_rewrite_tag working for Posts, but not working for Pages

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am having an issue using `add_rewrite_tag`. I've created some custom code to allow me to append a primary tag (which is a custom field I've setup that allows me to set a primary tag from the list of tags) to the front of a post's URL - e.g. `www.example.com/post-name/` becomes `www.example.com/primary-tag/post-name/`

This works as expected for **Posts**, but it stops **Pages** from working. When clicking on a page `www.example.com/page-name/` I just get the Index page. When removing the code Pages work fine again.

I have permalinks set as Custom Structure - `/%primary_tag%/%postname%/`

My code is as follows...

```
function custom_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%primary_tag%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

    $primary_tag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'primary_tag', true );
    if (!$primary_tag) return $permalink;

    $tag = get_tag( $primary_tag );
    if (!$tag) return $permalink;

    return str_replace('%primary_tag%', $tag->slug, $permalink);
}   
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%primary_tag%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

If anyone could point out where I'm going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.